# Open link in webView or safari from PDF page in iphone SDK?

Tags: iphone, pdf, quartz-2d

I am working on PDF Reader from last few days. I got lots of issues while dealing with PDF using Quartz 2D. Currently I want to do is My PDF has links in it. I want to open this link in UIWebView or Safari.

Is it possible using quartz 2D. I had tried it by display pdf in webview but then even it is not working.

I need to open link of PDF files in any of Safari or UIWebView.

EDIT:
I already have my PDF displayed. That PDF has text and a link to another website. When I click on that link I want to open that website, not any pdf. I know how to open PDF I want to know how to get link from PDF page and open it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the SO post for your answer

[Display pdf from the weburl iphone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457329/display-pdf-from-the-weburl-iphone-sdk/5457400#5457400)

here is a SO post for Opening a link in safari,

[Open Link in UIWebView in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330974/open-link-in-uiwebview-in-safari)

Here is SO post regarding

[How to access hyperlinks in PDF documents (iPhone)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247792/how-to-access-hyperlinks-in-pdf-documents-iphone)

[Get PDF hyperlinks on iOS with Quartz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080373/get-pdf-hyperlinks-on-ios-with-quartz)

Comment: Hi, I already have my PDF displayed. That PDF has text and a link to another website. When I click on that link I want to open that website, not any pdf. I know how to open PDF I want to know how to get link from PDF page and open it.

Comment: @Jaliya Thanks but this is not what I am looking for. My I am unable to detect my link in iphone. How can I detect the link and make request.

Comment: @Kapil : May you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905022/how-can-i-detect-phone-number-and-hyperlink-from-pdf-file